# Spring Boot LocalDate field serialization and deserialization

Tags: json, date, serialization, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

In Spring Boot 1.2.3.RELEASE with fasterxml what is the correct way of serializing and de-serializing a `LocalDate` field to ISO date formatted string?

I've tried:

- `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps:false` in application.properties file,
- including [jackson-datatype-jsr310](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310) in project and then using

  - `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` annotation
  - and `@DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE)` annotation,
- adding `Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory` as formatter with:

  ```
  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
      registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory());
  }
  ```

None of the above helped.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
compile ("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
```

in build.gradle
and then following annotations helped:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDate birthday;
```

Update: if you are using Spring Boot 2.*, the dependency is already included via one of the "starters".

Comment: This fixed it for me. I encountered the deserialization issue when I upgraded to use the 1.3.0.BUILD.SNAPSHOT version of spring boot.

Comment: can you specified you solution?

Comment: Yes you need the com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310 dependency and then you can use `@JsonDeserialize` `@JsonSerialize` annotations with the LocalDate field using LocalDateSerializer like in the answer.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on SpringBoot 1.3.6.RELEASE ;/ Getting error:
`com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.JSR310FormattedSerializerBase.findFormatOverrides(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value;`

Comment: solved my problem. with LocalDateTime jackson deserialization, thanks

Answer (score 15):

In my Spring Boot 2 applications

- `@JsonFormat` annotation is used in REST controllers when (de)serializing JSON data.
- `@DateTimeFormat` annotation is used in other controllers `ModelAttribute`s when (de)serializing String data.

You can specify both on the same field (useful if you share DTO between JSON and Thymeleaf templates):

```java
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") 
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private LocalDate birthdate;
```

Gradle dependency:

```groovy
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-json'
```

I hope this is all configuration you need for custom Date/Time formatting in Spring Boot 2.x apps.

---

For Spring Boot 1.x apps, specify additional annotations and dependency:

```java
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDate birthDate;

// or
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime birthDateTime;
```

```groovy
implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.9.8'
```

---

Be aware that your API will throw "JSON parse error" if somebody sends a date in a wrong format. Mapping example:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate releaseDate;
```

Exception example:

> `HttpMessageNotReadableException`: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "2002": Failed to deserialize `java.time.LocalDate`: (`java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`) Text '2002' could not be parsed at index 4; nested exception is `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException`: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "2002": Failed to deserialize `java.time.LocalDate`: (`java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`) Text '2002' could not be parsed at index 4

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a custom Java Date formatter, add the  `@JsonFormat` annotation.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDate birthdate;*
```

Comment: You should offer a way to set it globally. Adding `@JsonFormat` for every POJO is tedious. The answer from @chen should be the best.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it works if you just specify the dependency in the pom.xml.

With this, all my LocalDate fields automatically use the ISO format, no need to annotate them:

```
<!-- This is enough for LocalDate to be deserialized using ISO format -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Tested on Spring Boot 1.5.7.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of specifying the serializer/deserializer for all your LocalDate attributes, you might be interested in registering it globally. You need to override the configuration of the default ObjectMapper used by Spring for serialization/deserialization. Here is an example:

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Registro global do serializer/deserializer para datas sem horário
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        simpleModule.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer());
        simpleModule.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());

        mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

This way, Jackson will always use the specified serializer/deserializer for the data type defined, without the need to annotate your classes attributes.

Info: you must add the **jackson-databind** dependency to your pom.xml to have the custom serializer/deserializer code feature:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
    return builder -> {
        DateTimeFormatter localDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
        builder.serializerByType(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer(localDateFormatter));
        builder.deserializerByType(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer(localDateFormatter));

        DateTimeFormatter localDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        builder.serializerByType(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer(localDateTimeFormatter));
        builder.deserializerByType(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(localDateTimeFormatter));
    };
}
```

Comment: You should have mentioned that this will set the format globally in the Spring app.