# Creating JSON from httprequest and then parsing it

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

In my controller I want to parse httprequest (JSON sent by me) to create new ToDoItem. I will shoot POST at localhost:8080/todos/new with JSON and my controller should turn that httprequest to JSON and then parse data from it and use it in the contructor.
Here is my code so far:

```
// CREATE NEW TODOITEM FROM SENT JSON
@PostMapping("/todos/new")
public ResponseEntity<ToDoItem> newToDo(
        @RequestBody ToDoItem toDoItem,
        Principal principal
) {
    User currentUser = userRepository.findByUsername(principal.getName());
    toDoItemService.addToDo(toDoItem, currentUser);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(toDoItem);
}
```

Btw what would be the best choice to use as Date here? Is Calendar ok? Talking about parsing and sending it in a JSON.

EDIT:
My entity with annotations (setters and getters ommited):

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "TO_DO_ITEMS")
public class ToDoItem extends BaseEntity {

@Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false)
private String title;

@Column(name = "COMPLETED")
private boolean completed;

@Column(name = "DUE_DATE", nullable = false)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
protected LocalDate dueDate;

// a ToDoItem is only associated with one user
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private User user;


// JPA demands empty constructor
public ToDoItem() {}

public ToDoItem(User user, String title, LocalDate dueDate) {
    this.user = user;
    this.title = title;
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
}
```

And when I send:

```
{
"title":"testtodo",
"dueDate": [
    2017,
    10,
    06
]
}
```

I get Bad Request error:

```
{
"timestamp": 1485948636705,
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"exception":     "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
"message": "Could not read document: Invalid numeric value: Leading  zeroes not allowed\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4f15b887;   line: 6, column: 4]\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4f15b887;  line: 6, column: 3] (through reference chain:  com.doublemc.domain.ToDoItem[\"dueDate\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid numeric  value: Leading zeroes not allowed\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4f15b887; line: 6, column: 4]\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4f15b887; line: 6, column: 3] (through reference chain: com.doublemc.domain.ToDoItem[\"dueDate\"])",
"path": "/todos/new"
}
```

Comment: You can use this website to create a model in Java by just pasting a sample of your json: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

```
// CREATE NEW TODOITEM FROM SENT JSON
@PostMapping("/todos/new")
public String newToDo(@RequestBody TodoItem todoItem) {
    String title = todoItem.getTitle(); // extract title
    LocalDate dueDate = todoItem.getDueDate; // extract dueDate

    // getting logged in user
    User currentUser = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    User userFromDb = userRepository.findOne(currentUser.getId());


    ToDoItem newToDoItem = new ToDoItem(userFromDb, title, dueDate);
```

Note that you will need a converter to convert the date in json to `LocalDate` in your `ToDoItem` object. Research `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` for more info.

If you want to convert yourself, you can use a dto instead that has `dueDate` of type `String` and convert to `LocalDate` in java code and then convert the dto to your `ToDoItem` entity object.
`public String newToDo(@RequestBody TodoItemDto todoItemDto)`

I prefer `java.time.LocalDate`.

**UPDATE**
JSON deserializer can also be used here, checkout the following post:
[jsong deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871255/spring-boot-localdate-field-serialization-and-deserialization)

Comment: But if I use standard format for a LocalDate in JSON do I still have to use MessageConverter? Or then your code above works just fine?

Comment: Yes, you need. I haven't tried it in a while. I am pretty sure it was the case the last time I used it. You can also use JSON deserializer for that. I have updated my answer to include this.

Comment: Could you tell me how to use it? Should I add annotation in my Entity?  Added my entity to my post. I also updated my controller and psoted error whcih I'm getting

Comment: 1. make sure to add latest "jackson-datatype-jsr310" dependency.  2.The error msg shows that leading zeros are not allowed, make sure to change the 06 to 6 in your json.