# How do I indicate to Spring Boot to use UTC time zone for date parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following API

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDataToSeller> getTrackingDataByDate(@RequestBody RequestBodyBySeller requestBodyBySeller) {
    System.out.println(requestBodyBySeller.getEndDate());
    System.out.println(requestBodyBySeller.getEndDate().getDate());
    System.out.println(requestBodyBySeller.getEndDate().getHours());

public class RequestBodyBySeller {
    @ApiModelProperty(dataType="Date", notes = "endDate",required = true)
    Date endDate;
```

When I make a request with `"endDate": "2018-10-11"`, it prints

```
2018-10-11 16:54:45.897  INFO 11996 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 3 ms
Wed Oct 10 20:00:00 EDT 2018
10
20
```

This is messing up SQL queries because I'm testing if `hit_date <= #{endDate}`. It should be returning results from 2018-10-11 but it's not, because Spring Boot has interpreted the date as 2018-10-10. How can I get Spring Boot to use UTC time zone when parsing the date parameters to an API?

Spring Boot 1.5.13, MyBatis 3.4.5, MyBatis Spring 1.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the class to `java.time.LocalDate` and added this dependency

```
    <!-- For LocalDate to be deserialized using ISO format -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884603/148844

Answer (score 0):

Use [local date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), the problem is that when dates are involved, java tries to convert the date to the server timezone, since the is no time zone specified, it takes the hour ad UTC and then converts, LocalDate does not contain the timezone info, so, the date will be parsed as is.

Sorry, forgot to mention, to handle local date time you need to use [jackson-datatype-jsr310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871255/spring-boot-localdate-field-serialization-and-deserialization). Then, as the example says, you can annotate your class with:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDate birthdate;*
```

Comment: That didn't work. `Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalDate: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2018-10-11'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalDate: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2018-10-11')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@56bc399c; line: 1, column: 35]`

Comment: That won't compile. Eclipse gives the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<JodaDeserializers.LocalDateDeserializer> to Class<? extends JsonDeserializer>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is some way to define jackson feature in springmvc when you use springboot.

1. Use properties.
   `spring.jackson.xxxx`.
   Such as you want to set timezone. use add `spring.jackson.time-zone=xxx` in your `application.properties`
2. define a spring bean which implement `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`
3. you can directly create `ObjectMapper` bean in spring ,custom you want.

Comment: #1 didn't actually work. It still prints `Wed Oct 10 20:00:00 EDT 2018`. Even with a full restart. `spring.jackson.time-zone=UTC`

Comment: Your code print ‘’date“ show that it is EDT timezone。So you can set spring.jackson.time-zone=EDT to try。

Comment: I think i need say something more.You print the "date" show EDT timezone. This "EDT" was come from the jvm or your system.I think the cause is EDT is later UTC 4H.So  the UTC time ”2018-10-11“ was changed to EDT time "Wed Oct 10 20:00:00 EDT 2018".So you need keep the timezone the same ,spring.jackson.time-zone and the jvm (or system) timezone.

Comment: No, my development server is in EDT and the timestamps are in the database and are UTC and given in the API as UTC. I don't know how Spring Boot finds my time zone as I don't specify, but it might get it from the JVM or Windows. I don't want to set the time zone to EDT. It already knows my time zone is EDT. I just want to interpret the date in UTC zone or set the `Date` with UTC zone, because  the dates are in the DB as UTC and given on the API in UTC. I want to make my development server be like production, which will run in UTC zone.

Comment: In the case,you should change timezone with UTC in jvm