# Is there a way to configure LocalDate format for serializing and deserializing in the whole spring application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I have the following problem I hope someone can give me a hand:

Context: 3 Rest endpoints

1. Create (`register`)
2. Find (`findKid`)
3. Report (`listDashboardInfo`)

Requirement: Use the same date format `yyyyMMdd` for LocalDates in the whole application

Problem: Using `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = DateUtils.SHORT_DATE_PATTERN)` works for `register` and `listDashboardInfo` but not for `findKid`

These are the relevant parts of the code:

```
BODY
{
    "sailDate": "20191201"
}
@PostMapping(KID_PATH)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public KidDTO register(@RequestBody @Valid KidDTO kid) {
    return kidService.saveKid(kid);
}


GET /kid/0001::20190901
RESPONSE
{
    "sailDate": "2019-09-01"
}
@GetMapping(KID_FIND_PATH)
public CompletableFuture<KidDTO> findKid(@PathVariable String id) {
    return kidService.findKid(id);
}

GET /kid?shipCode=AL&sailDate=20190901
@GetMapping(KID_LIST_PATH)
public CompletableFuture<Slice<DashboardDTO>> listDashboardInfo(@Valid DashboardFilter filter, Pageable pageable) {
    return kidService.listKidsWithStatistics(filter, pageable);
}



@Getter
@Setter
public class DashboardFilter {
    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = DateUtils.SHORT_DATE_PATTERN)
    private LocalDate sailDate;
}

@Data
public class KidDTO {
    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = DateUtils.SHORT_DATE_PATTERN)
    private LocalDate sailDate;
}
```

Tests I did:

- spring.jackson.date-format in application.properties: From https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/08/parsing-of-localdate-query-parameters-in-spring-boot/ this just apply for Date not LocalDate.
- Using `@JsonFormat(pattern = DateUtils.SHORT_DATE_PATTERN)` the `listDashboardInfo` doesn't recognize the format and generates error

From stackoverflow I also found Spring doesn't use Jackson to deserialize query params so:
- I created a `@ControllerAdvice` with `@InitBinder` but the method `setAsText` is never called:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalDateBinder {
    @InitBinder
    public void binder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(LocalDate.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
            @Override
            public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                LocalDate.parse(text, DateUtils.SHORT_DATE_FORMATTER);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- Also I tried with a `@Bean public Formatter<LocalDate> localDateFormatter()` but nothing change:

```
    @Bean
    public FormattingConversionService conversionService() {
        DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService =
                new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);

        DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
        registrar.setDateFormatter(DateUtils.SHORT_DATE_FORMATTER);
        registrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);

        return conversionService;
    }

    @Bean
    public Formatter<LocalDate> localDateFormatter() {
        return new Formatter<LocalDate>() {
            @Override
            public LocalDate parse(String text, Locale locale) {
                return LocalDate.parse(text, DateUtils.SHORT_DATE_FORMATTER);
            }

            @Override
            public String print(LocalDate object, Locale locale) {
                return DateUtils.SHORT_DATE_FORMATTER.format(object);
            }
        };
    }
```

Any one has an idea of what is happening?

how to make the response of `findKid` be formatted?

How to configure the whole application with the same date format to works in serialization and parsing/deserializing processes?

**UPDATE**:

I found here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871255/spring-boot-localdate-field-serialization-and-deserialization` that I can use @JsonFormat for rest controllers (serialize and deserialize) and @DateTimeFormat for ModelView controllers but using both, at the same time, fixed my error so I don't understand why is that behavior if I only have rest controllers. Looks like in my case @DateTimeFormat deserialize and @JsonFormat serialize, is that the expected behavior? Is there any misconfiguration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add this bean to you configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter; // create your date formatter
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter; // create your date and time formatter
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule localDateModule = new SimpleModule();
        localDateModule.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class,
                new LocalDateDeserializer(formatter));
        localDateModule.addSerializer(LocalDate.class,
                new LocalDateSerializer(formatter));
        localDateModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class,
                new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(dateTimeFormatter));
        localDateModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class,
                new LocalDateTimeSerializer(dateTimeFormatter));

        mapper.registerModules(localDateModule);
        return mapper;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the property `spring.jackson.date-format` to any format you want inside you `application.properties` or `application.yml`.

Example with `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyyMMdd
```

Example with `application.yml`:

```
spring:
    jackson:
        date-format: yyyyMMdd
```

Source and other available properties: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html