# How to deserialize JSON containing LocalDate field generated by GSON library

Tags: json, jackson, gson, deserialization, localdate

I have JSON string which was generated by GSON library and it looks like :

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "articleNumber": 5009,
    "processDate": {
      "year": 2021,
      "month": 1,
      "day": 1
    },
    "price": 1.22
}
```

I want to use Jackson for deserialize the above JSON. But it fails at `processDate` field due to the format how `processDate` field is present in the JSON.

How to parse the above JSON string by using some custom deserializer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot LocalDate field serialization and deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871255/spring-boot-localdate-field-serialization-and-deserialization)

Comment: @ℛɑƒæĿᴿᴹᴿ There the date field is not in object format. It is just like "processDate" : "2021-01-01"

Comment: Why not simply make it a in ISO 8601 format so that _every_ your component (at least Java 8 Time API aware of course) could be aware of that? Add a `LocalDate`-to-`String` serializer to `Gson` first.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you unwillingly got Jackson's built-in
[`LocalDateDeserializer`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-jsr310/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/LocalDateDeserializer.html) parsing your date.
This deserializer supports several JSON date formats
(string, integer array, epoch day count)

- `"2021-1-1"`
- `[2021, 1, 1]`
- `18627`

but unfortunately not your object-like format

- `{ "year": 2021, "month" :1, "day": 1 }`

Therefore you need to write your own deserializer for `LocalDate`.
This is not so hard.

```
public class LocalDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
        try {
            int year = node.get("year").intValue();
            int month = node.get("month").intValue();
            int day = node.get("day").intValue();
            return LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw JsonMappingException.from(parser, node.toString(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your Java class you need to tell Jackson,
that you want its `processDate` property be deserialized
by your own `LocalDateDeserializer`.

```
public class Root {

    private int id;

    private int articleNumber;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate processDate;

    private double price;
    
    // getters and setters (omitted here for brevity)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont know java that well, just make a custom type like this. below
just create a custom Struct like:

```java
inline class processDate {
    int year,
    int month,
    int day,
    public Date getDate(){
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
        Date date = formatter.parse(this.day + "-" + this.month + "-" + this.year);
        return date;
    }

}
```